# Is it better to avoid ReLu as activation function if input data has plenty of negative values?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

ReLu is probably the most popular activation function in machine learning today. Yet, ReLu function outputs 0 when input data values are negative. ReLu totally disregards negative data. This may result in information loss. Is it better to avoid ReLu as activation function if input data has plenty of negative values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, because the activation function of choice isn't applied directly on the input data. The earliest it is applied is after the first layer: $a(Wx+b)$, which is when the weights are properly initialized, leads to both positive and negative inputs into the activation.

Edit: I specified proper initialization because it is important. Typically, weights are initialized to small random values distributed symmetrically about $0$, and biases are initialized to exactly $0$. This means that initially, inputs are split roughly evenly between positive and negative, which is a good starting point since we would like to be within the general region in which the nonlinearities of relu can be exploited.

Comment: +1 I really liked your answer and your contribution to the CV community.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. However, there is no guarantee that weights and biases will lead to positive inputs into the activation function. Substantial number of the inputs can still be negative after being influenced by the weights and biases.

Comment: @curious that is the point of the ReLu (non-linearity), if everything are positive then, you are just getting the exact values as inputs.

Comment: Oh ... I see. MAkes sense. Marked your answer as the answer.

Comment: @curious i edited my answer to add a comment about the initialization

Comment: I would add that it’s also pretty standard to normalize your input data so that the mean is zero. Neural networks can struggle to optimize data that starts out far away from zero regardless of whether it is positive or negative.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28191414 for more info

Comment: I would also add that since most deep networks use batch normalization, you do not need to worry about your XW+b distribution being all negative because BatchNormalization(XW+b) will have a unit variance distribution centered around zero, thus the inputs to the ReLU function will not be all negative.

Answer (score 2):

No, the data that feed into the activation function is already transformed, e.g., you are feeding X*W but not X.